# How set size NSWindow, relative NSTextField height?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How to set size of NSWindow relatively to the height of NSTextField ?

Comment: Are you looking to change the text field's height (if so, why?), or keep its height the same while resizing the window?

Answer (score 0):

There is NSButton in my application. When it is pushed NSTextField is loaded with the new text from web service. So that means that the height of NSTextField is always dynamic.